# Pandas, filter rows which column contain another column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I filter rows which column contain another column?
For example, if we have DT with two columns A, B, can we filter rows with B.contains(A)? Not just if B contains some A values from all A from DT, but just in one row.

```
A      B
'lol'  'lolec'
'ram'  'rambo'
'ki'   'pio'

Result:
A     B
'lol'  'lolec'
'ram'  'rambo'
```

Comment: What is output if values `lolec` and `pio` are swapped?

Comment: Then in result will be only second row.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by `apply` and `in` if need filter columns `A` and `B` per rows:

```
#if necessary strip ' in all values
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("'"))
#df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip("'"))

print (df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)]
print (df)
     A      B
0  lol  lolec
1  ram  rambo
```

**Difference of solutions** - input `DataFrame` is changed:

```
print (df)
     A      B
0  lol    pio
1  ram  rambo
2   ki  lolec

print (df[df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)])
     A      B
1  ram  rambo

print (df[df['B'].str.contains("|".join(df['A']))])
    A      B
1  ram  rambo
2   ki  lolec
```

for improve performance use list comprehension:

```
df = df[[a in b for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is usefull. I have little problem with encoding. Encoding was always big problem in python 2.7 for me.

Comment: Is possible switched to python 3? I switched 6 months ago and it was good decision.

Comment: I think it's time:)

Comment: @jezrael How can I do this if 1st column is int64 and 2nd column is float? I get an error saying 'int' is not iterable when I run df[df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)].

Comment: I tried df1 = df[df['parent'].isin(df['child'])] as well as df1 = df[df['parent'].astype('int64').isin(df['child'])] but both do not filter out records that I expect to be filtered out, i.e., 'parent' values that are not present in 'child' column.

Comment: @Sikander - Hard to know what is problem without data - both columns are integers?

Comment: One column (child) is int64 and the other is float (Parent). I need to filter out any rows that do not have Parent in Child column. For example, if 123 is present in Parent column, say, in row #10 but not present in any rows of the Child column, then I need to delete this row.

Comment: @Sikander - Is possible see data sample?

Comment: @jezrael I just asked a question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273144/python-pandas-delete-rows-where-value-in-one-column-is-not-present-in-another-c

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to match each of the substrings by using the regex `|` character which implies an `OR` selection from the contents of the other series:

```
df[df['B'].str.contains("|".join(df['A']))]
```

[image]