# Pandas, check if a column contains characters from another column, and mark out the character？

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 2 Dataframe, df1 & df2. e.g.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'col1': ['12abc12', '12abcbla', 'abc', 'jh']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': ['abc', 'efj']})
```

what i want looks like this (find all the rows which contains the character from `df2`, and tag them out)

```
   index      col1      col2
0      1   12abc12       abc
1      2  12abcbla       abc
2      3       abc       abc
3      4        jh
```

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829645/pandas-filter-rows-which-column-contain-another-column) but not exactly what i want. Thx for any ideas in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) if need first matched value:

```
df1['new'] = df1['col1'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(df2["col2"])})', expand=False).fillna('')
print (df1)
   index      col1  new
0      1   12abc12  abc
1      2  12abcbla  abc
2      3       abc  abc
3      4        jh
```

If need all matched values use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'col1': ['12abc1defj2', '12abcbla', 'abc', 'jh']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': ['abc', 'efj']})

df1['new'] = df1['col1'].str.findall("|".join(df2["col2"])).str.join(',')
print (df1)
   index         col1      new
0      1  12abc1defj2  abc,efj
1      2     12abcbla      abc
2      3          abc      abc
3      4           jh
```

Comment: how about `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': ['abc', 'a', 'efj']})`?, 'a' will not included

Comment: @Sean.H - `findall` not working with overalaping values, so need `df1['new'] = [','.join(y for y in df2['col2'] if y in x) for x in df1['col1']]`