# Python/Pandas: Delete rows where value in one column is not present in another column in the same data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame containing a multi-parent hierarchy of employees.  Node (int64) is a key that identifies each unique combination of employee and manager. Parent (float64) is a key that represents the manager in the ‘node’.

Due to some source data anomalies, there are parent keys present in the data frame that are not 'nodes'.  I would like to delete all such rows where this is occurring.

| empId | empName | mgrId | mgrName | node | parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Alice | 222 | Bob | 1 | 3 |
| 111 | Alice | 333 | Charlie | 2 | 4 |
| 222 | Bob | 444 | Dave | 3 | 5 |
| 333 | Charlie | 444 | Dave | 4 | 5 |
| 444 | Dave |  |  | 5 |  |
| 555 | Elizabeth | 333 | Charlie | 6 | 7 |

In the above sample, it would be employee ID 555 because parent key 7 is not present anywhere in ‘node’ column.

Here's what I tried so far:

This removes some rows but does not remove all. Not sure why?

```
df1 = df[df['parent'].isin(df['node'])]
```

I thought maybe it was because ‘parent’ is float and ‘node’ is int64, so I converted and tried but same result as previous.

```
df1 = df[df['parent'].astype('int64').isin(df['node'])]
```

Something to consider is that the data frame contains around 1.5 million rows.

I also tried this, but this just keeps running the code forever - I'm assume this is because .map will loop through the entire data frame (which is around 1.5 million rows):

```
df[df['parent'].map(lambda x: np.isin(x, df['node']).all())]
```

I'm especially perplexed, when I use the first 2 code snippets, as to why it would consistently filter out a small subset of rows that do not meet the filter condition but not all.

Again, 'parent' is float64 and has empty values.  'node' is int64 and has no empty values. A more realistic example of node and parent keys is as follows:

Node   -   13192210227

Parent -   12668210227.0

Comment: In this example, suppose the parent in the first row is 6 not 3. Then once the last row is removed, the parent of the first row would also not be a node anymore right? In that case, what should we do with the first row?

Comment: Have you tried converting them to integer and then to string?

Comment: @enke We would have to drop the 1st row as well, in that case, I believe.

Comment: @JohnGiorgio Do you mean perform the filtering on strings as opposed to float and integer? I thought about that but converting 'parent' to string may result in something like '6.0' which will not match with '6' during string comparison. Maybe I can truncate the decimal point and 0 before comparing? I'll try that and see if that works.

Comment: @Sikander then a simple `isin` can't solve your problem. I think you'll have to build a directed graph and eliminate the nodes that has no one edge pointing to it.

Comment: @enke You make a valid point.  I tested this with a couple of examples and it does end up complicating things.  Do you have any ideas or good references to how I can build a DG and eliminate nodes with no edges?